# Creating a for loop for 3 different variables with 3 different conditions in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve the famous Moneyball problem. I have the datasets and I'm trying to find 3 player that fit these 3 conditions:

1. The total combined salary of the three players can not exceed 15 million dollars.
2. Their combined number of At Bats (AB) needs to be equal to or greater than the lost players.
3. Their mean OBP has to be equal to or greater than the mean OBP of the lost players

Here are my values:

- Mean OBP <- meanobp <- 0.3638687
- At Bats Lost <- atbatslost <- 1469

My Data:

- year2001 <- All the players from 2001 with their Salary, OBP and AB
  listed as columns.

The for loop that I tried that didnt quite work:

```
for (x in 1:nrow(year2001)){
  for (y in 1:nrow(year2001)){
    for (z in 1:nrow(year2001)){
      if ((((year2001$salary[x]+year2001$salary[y]+year2001$salary[z]) <= 15000000)) = T & 
          ((year2001$AB[x]+year2001$AB[y]+year2001$AB[z]) >= 1469) = T & 
          (((year2001$OBP[x]+year2001$OBP[y]+year2001$OBP[z])/3) >= meanobp) = T){
        print(x)
        print(y)
        print(z)
         }
      }
  }
}
```

When I run this I get the following outcome:

```
>         print(x)
[1] 1
>         print(y)
[1] 1
>         print(z)
[1] 50
>       }
Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I checked to see if the (1, 1, 50) rows gives me the answer and it doesnt.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Two things: (1) you are using `= T` when I think you intend to use `== T`; the first is ***assignment***, the second is *comparison*; (2) you typically don't need `if (cond == T)`, as `if (cond)` by itself often works just as well (there are certainly exceptions to this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing some of the comments - providing a reproducible example of your problem/question is important. Here's one possible solution to what you're trying to do though; using the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(8675309)

player.names <- c("Jeff", "Stan", "Hadley", "Mary", "Helen", "Susan", "Mark", "Marcus", "Juan", "Pablo", "Aamir", "Geoff")
player.salaries <- 1:12 * 1000000
player.ab <- seq(1, 36, 3) * 100
player.obp <- runif(12, 0, 1)

player.df <- data.frame(name = player.names,
                        salary = player.salaries,
                        ab = player.ab,
                        obp = player.obp,
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

player.combinations <- expand.grid(player1 = player.names,
                                   player2 = player.names,
                                   player3 = player.names,
                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(p1.num = as.numeric(as.factor(player1)),
         p2.num = as.numeric(as.factor(player2)),
         p3.num = as.numeric(as.factor(player3))) %>% 
  ## filter step ensures no duplicates or flipped orderings
  filter(p1.num < p2.num, p2.num < p3.num) %>% 
  left_join(rename(player.df, p1.salary = salary, p1.ab=ab, p1.obp = obp), 
            by = c("player1"="name")) %>%
  left_join(rename(player.df, p2.salary = salary, p2.ab=ab, p2.obp = obp), 
            by = c("player2"="name")) %>%
  left_join(rename(player.df, p3.salary = salary, p3.ab=ab, p3.obp = obp), 
            by = c("player3"="name")) %>%
  filter(p1.salary+p2.salary+p3.salary<=15000000,
         p1.ab+p2.ab+p3.ab >= 1469,
         (p1.obp+p2.obp+p3.obp)/3 >= 0.3638687)
```

Comment: I applied the code you wrote to my data and it resulted with "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.7 Gb". This might be due to the fact that i have only 8 GB of ram on my system but I'm not sure. I tried to set memory.limit(6000) and it crashed my whole system. I'm fairly new to programming and R so I can't really tell what the problem is. I created the player.combinations data frame by itself and it's actually made out of 766 million observations. Thanks for your help!

Comment: how many players are in your data.frame? It sounds like you might want to try to filter out some players before doing the `expand.grid` function.

Comment: 915 that are just in the year 2001 which I also saved as a data frame. So 915 in total. I think I'm gonna filter out the ones that are really expensive and the ones that have value of 0 in OBP and AB.